# Certain web pages not opening properly in Chrome, Opera etc

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, router, dns

I am stumped. If I try to open google.com the front page works. Then I do a search, "test" for example. What I get is a many years old version of Google, with the serif logo and Search tools not working at all etc. And the search is faulty too. This ONLY happens on Chrome, Opera and Torch, all using the same engine. I tried loading without extensions, no difference. Also if I go to Chrome Settings / Change proxy settings, it goes to Internet Properties and there is nothing in the VPN settings. However, in Firefox, Google works just normally.

I also restarted my router. What can possibly cause this?

Another computer on the same network has no problems with Chrome. Also, there is at least one web page that doesn't load at all on the problematic computer (not even in Firefox). Additionally, I found out that if on the problematic computer I do enable a VPN connection, then Google stops working at all (I sometimes use Cisco AnyConnect, but if I quit that, I assume it is completely gone at that point).

Comment: Change proxy is supposed to go to normal Internet properties so that's not such a concern. Those browsers are all powered by WebKit, it could be possible you have some form of malware targeting those. Do you have up to date AV software? It might be worth running something like Malwarebytes just to make sure you're in the clear.

Comment: Yes I have had up to date ESET NOD32 for many years. I just ran Malwarebytes. Almost clean, it found PUT.Optional.OutBrowse and PUP.Optional.CytiWeb but I don't think those were the problem. Removed those but no difference. What can I try next?

Comment: Ah, I noticed that IE and Safari are "affected" too in my Windows. Only Firefox (which is set on No proxy) gives me the normal Google. A certain specific web page behaves weirdly; if I load it several times on Chrome, some times it works. However Google is always the old version except on Firefox.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: http://s24.postimg.org/9d3a14j79/broken_google.png (there is Search tools, but that doesn't work, just refreshes the page).

Comment: I found a solution (partial or complete solution, I'm not sure): **Internet Options / Connections / LAN settings / [x] Use automatic configuration script** was injected with http://localhost.world/localhost.local and that downloaded a script with all Google requests being forwarded to PROXY 69.197.188.122:8484. So I was incorrect about the proxy settings being empty. I only looked at Proxy, but the automatic configuration does the same thing basically.

Comment: Yup, it's a very nasty trojan, not yet identified by antivirus software. For proper removal instructions, see http://www.tenforums.com/antivirus-firewalls-system-security/27107-google-redirection-localhost-world-8.html